# Create Oozie coordinator without end date with Hue

Tags: oozie, hue, oozie-coordinator

Can I create an infinite Oozie coordinator that doesn't expire (without end date) with Hue?

Please, help!

Comment: can you give more details why you need this ? you can always set the end date to be year 3016 ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can not create a coordinator which will never expire. Here is the [Oozie Coordinator](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/client/src/main/resources/oozie-coordinator-0.5.xsd) xsd reference:

```
    <xs:attribute name="start" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="end" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
```

The like `start`, `end` is also a required attribute.

You can created a coordinator which expires after a long time like 100 years. Technically that will be something like `never expire` only.